# Hide/show scrollbar from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension, scrollbar, content-script

I'm trying to hide\show scrollbars on pages via my Chrome Extension.

I hide it by inserting this CSS from background.js file:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none !important;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
    display: none !important;
}
```

and I try to show it again by inserting this CSS from background.js file:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: block !important;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Hiding works, but I'm unable to restore it afterwards. When I inspect the page through Chrome DevTools, it shows as if both of the inserted CSS are active at same time.

Is there any other way to do this?
Important thing to note is that this should work on any page, so I'm able to remove and restore scrollbars from any page CSS is inserted to.

I'm open for any other way, JavaScript too.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions you almost always need to include your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML, and often webpage HTML/scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't my code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I accomplished this through content-script.
This code removes scrollbars and still allows you to scroll with mousewheel or keyboard buttons:

```
    var styleElement = document.createElement('style');
    styleElement.id = 'remove-scroll-style';
    styleElement.textContent =
        'html::-webkit-scrollbar{display:none !important}' +
        'body::-webkit-scrollbar{display:none !important}';
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(styleElement);
```

And this code restores scrollbars:

```
$('#remove-scroll-style').remove();
```

Comment: Don't use `.innerHTML` here. Use `.textContent`. Why are you mixing vanilla JavaScript and jQuery? For the little you're doing here you *really* shouldn't be loading jQuery (85KiB of minimized code) just to save a few characters over using vanilla JavaScript: `document.getElementById('remove-scroll-style').remove();`

Comment: I need jQuery for other things, this is just a part of the code. And jQuery is loaded locally from Chrome Extension, so it's not a problem. Thanks for .textContent advice, I forgot about it.

Answer (score 0):

This example may give you a hint on how to do it:

https://jsfiddle.net/PVZB8/139/

It's using CSS and JavaScript to achieve the result, but it seems like you can achieve that by using only CSS (example given on *jsfiddle*):

```
div.mousescroll {
    overflow: hidden;
}
div.mousescroll:hover {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: This solution is restricted to single div, I need it to work for whole page and for each page. Also, I need to preserve mouse scroll/ keyboard arrows functionality, so that user is able to scroll even though scrollbars are hidden